# How can I write a function to evaluate custom datatype

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj, ml

```
datatype mixed_expression =
   ME_NUM of int
 | ME_PLUS of mixed_expression * mixed_expression
 | ME_TIMES of mixed_expression * mixed_expression
 | ME_LESSTHAN of mixed_expression * mixed_expression;

datatype value =
   INT_VAL of int
 | BOOL_VAL of bool
 | ERROR_VAL;
```

I am given these data types and this is my approach

```
fun eval e = 
  case e of 
    ME_NUM x       => INT_VAL x 
  | ME_PLUS (l, r) => eval l + eval r
```

I got the following error message.

```
**Error: overloaded variable not defined at type
  symbol: +
  type: value**
```

I have no clues on how to solve these issues since I am not allowed to use mutation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you what you need to know. When you write:

```
eval l + eval r
```

The expressions `eval l` and `eval r` yield type `value`. There is no `+` operator for this type.

As a style note, your `case` is extraneous in this situation.

```
fun eval(ME_NUM x)       = INT_VAL x
  | eval(ME_PLUS (l, r)) = eval l + eval r
```

You should also get a warning about pattern-matching being non-exhaustive as you haven't handled `ME_TIMES` or `ME_LESSTHAN`.

Really, what you need to do is define a function which can *add* two `value` values.

```
fun me_add(INT_VAL a, INT_VAL b)  = INT_VAL (a + b)
  | me_add(INT_VAL a, BOOL_VAL b) = (* ... *)
```

There are lots of combinations you'll need to pattern-match on. You may want to just define a function that coerces a `value` into an `int`.

```
fun toInt(INT_VAL a)      = a
  | toInt(BOOL_VAL True)  = 1
  | toInt(BOOL_VAL False) = 0
  | (* and so on... *)
```

Then you could write something like:

```
fun me_add(a, b) = INT_VAL(toInt a + toInt b)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is no `+` operator defined for the `value` type.
(You would not solve this by using mutation.)

You need to "pick apart" the results of `eval` and then build a new `value` from the addition.

The most naive approach would be a case analysis, but this gets unreadable very quickly:

```
  eval (ME_PLUS (e1, e2)) = (case eval e1 of
                                   INT_VAL x1 => (case eval e2 of
                                                      INT_VAL x2 => INT_VAL (x1 + x2)
                                                    | _ => ERROR_VAL)
                                 | _ => ERROR_VAL)
```

and you would need one of these uglinesses for each case.

A tidier approach is to define the operations on `value`s as separate functions:

```
fun add (INT_VAL x1) (INT_VAL x2) = INT_VAL (x1 + x2)
  | add _ _ = ERROR_VAL;
```

and so on.
Then you define your interpreter in terms of these operations:

```
fun eval (ME_NUM x) = INT_VAL x
  | eval (ME_PLUS (e1, e2)) = add (eval e1) (eval e2)
  | eval (ME_TIMES (e1, e2)) = multiply (eval e1) (eval e2)
  | eval (ME_LESSTHAN (e1, e2)) = less_than (eval e1) (eval e2);
```